# PHP - Exec on user's GUI session

Tags: macos, bash, php, applescript

I am trying to get a PHP script to execute an Applescript which opens an application.*

PHP is running under the `_www` user. And while it *can* execute Applescripts with the `osascript` command, it can't run my Applescript program, because `_www` **has no desktop environment**.

So I thought: I'll just use `sudo` to run the AppleScript under *my* user. I used `visudo` to add an entry for `_www` which would allow it run my script without a password (`sudo -u myUser ...`). This worked great! `sudo` switched the user to me and ran most commands without a hitch. *Except I still didn't have a desktop environment!* I could run shell-only commands; `whoami` returned my username, not `_www`. But AppleScript failed to work. I had switched the user, but had not switched into a desktop environment.

So, my question: **is there a way that PHP can execute programs in another user's desktop environment?** I suspect not...

---

As an alternative, I thought I might establish a local-socket link between my PHP program (running as `_www`) and another program running under my user. The latter program will listen on the socket until PHP sends a message. Perhaps I'll do this if the above doesn't work.

---

*In the interest of full transparency, what I'm actually trying to do: I want to send an iMessage to myself. Apple being Apple, the **only** way of programmatically send iMessages is through AppleScript-ing the Messages app. Messy, but it works.

*If there is no way to do either of the above*, I'll just use SMS and forget iMessage.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236431/how-can-i-launch-a-local-application-on-osx-from-php-running-mamp

Comment: I'm not an apple person (but I am a Linux person).  I'm pretty sure the issue you are having relates to the application not knowing how to connect to the X Window (ie the screen driver).    (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607777/what-display-settings-needed-for-running-sh-installer-for-java-7-ee-sdk-on-mac)

"DISPLAY=:0 ; sudo -u myUser ..."

Comment: huh, I've done that a million times on linux but never thought to do it on OSX (because it doesn't quite use X in the same way). I'll take a look.